# a write() to tun/tap interface returns "invalid argument"

Tags: c++, linux, qt, tun-tap

I have successfully created and attached to a tap interface.
I can also read from the interface with no problem.
But trying to write to it fails reporting "invalid argument". The code follows :

```
int TapInterface::write(char *buf, int n)
{
  int nwrite;
  if((nwrite=::write(this->my_tap_fd, buf, n))<0)
 {
   qDebug("Writing data") ;
   perror("Error:");
   exit(1);
  }
  return nwrite;
}
....
....
QByteArray txData("hello");
write(txData.data(), txData.length());
```

Any help?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Sorry, for the late response; the write function returns -1 i.e. ::write(this->my_tap_fd, buf, n) thus the if statement is entered and the  "invalid argument" error code is reported by perror. The last two lines in the code show how I actually called the function

Comment: Are you sure your `QIODevice` is correcly opened?

Comment: As it can be seen what i have written into the tap interface is a sample "hello" msg! Could this be the source of the problem? Should it be a valid ethernet frame/ ip packet?

Comment: @Miki; for this part I have used direct sys calls (i.e. open, write, etc,...) and the open sys call and the corresponding ioctl call to create/attech to the interface return sucessfully . Actually i have followed the simpletun.c example @ http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

Comment: @Miki; BTW as I mentioned in my post i can successfully read out of the interface, so the interface must have been correctly opened (i guess).

Comment: Can you go inside the body of the write that gives you the error?

Comment: I try to step into the function but nothing happens!! After many repeated F11 (step into) the debugger moves to the next line (i.e. inside the if function)

Comment: Try writing your txData to a file, and check if your TapInterface::write writes data correctly. If so, your problem is in ::write

Comment: do you have the necessary permissions?

Comment: solved, as i guessed: the data written to the tun/tap interface should be a valid pkt/frame